# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $1\neq 0$. Let $a$ be a nilpotent element, $x$ be a unit . Then $1+a$ is not a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $1\neq 0$. Let $a$ be a nilpotent element, $x$ be a unit. Then
>
> (A) $1+a$ is not a unit.
>
> (B) $a-x$ is a nilpotent element.
>
> (C) $a+x$ is a unit.
>
> (D) None of the above.

My work : $(1+a)(1-a+a^2+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}a^{n-1})=1$ where $n$ is the smallest integer such that $a^n=0$ . So (A) is false .

In $Z_8$  the element $2$ is nilpotent and $1$ is unit but $3=1+2$ is not nilpotent . So (B) is false .

(C) If I think $y=a^{-1}(1-xa^{-1}+x^2a^2+...+(-1)^{n-1} x^{n-1}a^{n-1} $ is inverse of $a+x$ . I found this vis expansion : $y^{-1}=\frac{a^{-1}}{1+xa^{-1}}=1+xa^{-1}....$

So (C) is true indeed .

Comment: A nilpotent element of a ring cannot have an inverse, so $a^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, (C) is the only true statement.  However, your proof is wrong since it uses $a^{-1}$.

Instead, note that
$$
x^{-1}(a + x) = 1 + (ax^{-1})
$$
is necessarily a unit since $ax^{-1}$ is nilpotent.  Since $x^{-1}(a+x)$ is a unit, so is $a + x$.

---

Along the same lines, you could use your expansion for
$$
y = \frac{x^{-1}}{1 + ax^{-1}}
$$